# Fast Enumeration..How do I know when it's finished? Completion block?

Tags: objective-c, core-bluetooth

I have a BLEPeripheral that holds about thirty CBCHaracteristics. I'm building an app that interfaces with a custom BLE device. When the view loads I need to write, read, and subscribe to Characteristics on that device. The problem I'm having is I'm not sure when all my Characteristics have been assigned to the data model and if I try to load my view before thats finished my app will crash. I've confirmed this by adding a count integer and incrementing the count after it discovers each characteristic, then when my count int == 30, I load the UI. This feel extremely clunky and I feel like theres a better way to do this.

I'm trigger the loading of the data on the UI view with an observer notification. To give a little more information, I'm using a splitview, user selects the ble object that want to connect to. Once it's connected it hides the splitview and shows the detailview.

```
- (void)peripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService:(CBService *)service error:(NSError *)error {

for (CBCharacteristic *characteristic in service.characteristics) {

        if(_itemCount == 30) {
            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"STOPINDICATOR" object:self];
        }

        // Serial Number
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:SERIAL_NUMBER]]) {
            _serialNumber = characteristic;
            _itemCount++;
        }

        // MFG Name
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MFG_NAME]]) {
            _mfgName = characteristic;
            _itemCount++;

        }

        // Device Type
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:DEVICE_TYPE]]) {
            _deviceType = characteristic;
            _itemCount++;

        }

        // Model Number
        if ([characteristic.UUID isEqual:[CBUUID UUIDWithString:MODEL_NUMBER]]) {
            _modelNumber = characteristic;
           _itemCount++;

        }
}
```

}

Comment: I think you need to provide more detail about your issue as I suspect that the obvious answer - the loop is finished when the statement following it is executed - is probably not what you are asking. Edit your question to provide the detail (don't put it in comments).

Comment: You can update your UI updatation code after for loop. There is not any trigger. Still if  you want to check you can user counter variable.

Comment: "for (...){//Do something}//For Loop ended!. But, if it's because your are waiting for the callback "didDiscoverCharacteristic", that's another issue, but your question isn't clear.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood properly your question. But you can check if your `CBCharacteristic` is the latest one, for instance. `if ([characteristic isEqualTo:[service.characteristics lastObject]]) { ...... }` With this you will check if it is the last element.

Comment: Will that give me the last characteristic of the current service or the complete end of the enumeration? Because I have six services that get iterated through.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work, it's triggering at the end of each service. Each service holds at set of characteristics and the enumeration iterates through service 1, then each characteristic, service 2 -> characteristics and so on. So when I output that I get 6 values, one for each service.